# jquery form validation not working - please help! :)

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Click on the big button on the landing page. Then click on "medical school"

You will then see a form pop up. I marked a lot of fields with the class "required" (such as first name, last name, etc.) but the form still submits even when these fields are left blank.

(1) Can you please help me figure out how to prevent the form from submitting when the required fields are left blank, and also --
(2) When a required field is left blank, the field should turn red, or have a red border. (I don't want to show error message text because it will make my form look more cluttered.)

This is my code:

HTML (this is only part of it):

```
    <input type="text" name="entry.384987407" id="entry_384987407" placeholder="First" class="ss-q-short required" />

    <input type="text" name="entry.290934326" id="entry_290934326" placeholder="Last" class="ss-q-short required" />

    <br />

    <label class="ss-q-item-label uniform">
    Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="entry.1440270198" id="entry_1440270198"         placeholder="Email" class="ss-q-short required" />

    </div>


    <div id="optional-form">
    Optional form goes here
    </div>
```

Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    $("#ss-form").validate({

   errorPlacement: function(){
        return true;  // suppresses error message text
    },
    submitHandler: function() { 

         $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
      $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
          });

         $("#entry_384987407").keyup(function () {
        var firstnameMD = $(entry_384987407).val();
    var lastnameMD = $(entry_290934326).val();
    var emailMD = $(entry_1440270198).val();

        $(".guysname").text(firstnameMD);

        }).keyup();


         form.submit(); // this MUST be AFTER everything else!!!!
         } //end of what happens when a VALID form is submitted (submitHandler)

     }); // end of function validate
     }); //end of general function


    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: Your 'required' keyword has been put in the class declaration for the `First Name` field, and probably others too.

Comment: @MikeW What's wrong with that? It's how the plugin works.

Comment: Please add the relevant bits of HTML here, don't refer to the production web page. Remember, this page will be accessed for years in the future, but you're going to fix the web page.

Comment: OK, I added the relevant bits of HTML. @MikeW - I did putu the "required" as a class.... isn't that where it's supposed to go?

Comment: @Barmar He's using other HTML5 attributes. I assumed that he'd be using HTML5's `required` keyword too.

Comment: Oh!  I figured it out!  I shouldn't have written "required" as a class... I should have just written it straight in the <input> tag.

Comment: How can I make it highlight the required fielsd in red when they are left empty, instead of showing the error text?

Comment: You do that with CSS.

Comment: Where would I put the CSS?

Comment: Also - do you know why my fade in / fade out effect is not working? (see jquery code)

Comment: You've written custom `keyup` handlers.  This is not nessessary since the plugin already handles all key-up events automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
$('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

With

```
$('#required-form').fadeOut("slow");
$('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
```

And Replace this

```
var firstnameMD = $(entry_384987407).val();
var lastnameMD = $(entry_290934326).val();
var emailMD = $(entry_1440270198).val();
```

With

```
var firstnameMD = $('#entry_384987407').val();
var lastnameMD = $('#entry_290934326').val();
var emailMD = $('#entry_1440270198').val();
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I accidentally left out the '# in the jQuery. That helped.   The fade in / fade out is still not working, though....

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the OP running `fadeIn` within the callback function for `fadeOut`, and why you think running `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` simultaneously will solve anything here.

Comment: I put fadeIn within fadeOut because I want the fadeOut to happen first, and then when it's finished, it should fadeIn.  Is there a better way to write that code? I think jQuery has something like "fade out... and when finished, fade in" but I don't know how to write the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Are you sure you have this tag in your html code `<div id="required-form">`
If yes then everything should work fine. I tried this in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/9VYcY/